# VBA date double quotation mark gives triple quotation mark

Tags: excel, vba, date, macros, double-quotes

I have a strange problem with my Excel VBA code. I have a date string column in a CSV spreadsheet which I would like to wrap around in double quotation marks.
I wrote a VBA script in Excel to achieve this. However, everytime I run my script, the date string output is wrapped in three sets of double quotation marks instead of just one.

I get this:

```
"""2015-11-11 00:00:00.40""",59845,-0.20375,3.447,2.0135,32.08286,12,32,11.6
```

Instead of this:

```
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.40",59845,-0.20375,3.447,2.0135,32.08286,12,32,11.6
```

Where could I be going wrong? I have tried using `CHAR(34)` and also `CHR(34)` to represent `"` but that has not helped.
Here is my script:

```
    Sub Quotations()
'
' Quotations Macro
'

'
Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("E:\Copy\*.csv")

    ' Create new workbook and assign to variable
    Dim wb As Workbook


    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Windows("PERSONAL.XLSB").Activate
    wb.Activate
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;E:\Copy\" + StrFile, Destination:= _
        Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "E:\Copy\" + StrFile
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CHR(34)&RC[-9]&CHR(34)"
    Range("J2").Select
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 23.57
    Range("J1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J1:J864000")
    Range("J1:J864000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "E:\Copy\quotes\" + StrFile, FileFormat:= _
        xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=False
    StrFile = Dir
    Loop
 End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

> "Fields containing a line-break, double-quote, and/or commas should be
>   quoted"

When you save your modified file as CSV, Excel sees the quotes you added and so adds quotes around those fields.  When it does that it also doubles-up the quotes you added to *escape* them (so they will not be interpreted as field quotes by the program parsing the saved file)

If you re-open your CSV file in Excel you'll see that it is parsed correctly, and only the single set of quotes you added will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the program that I am using needs to open the file as a text document outside of Excel. Is there anything that I can do to remove the extra quotes other than opening each file and manually replacing the extra quotes using the Find and Replace function?